# Can PHP close the connection to client?

Tags: php, apache, http, testing, network-programming

I'm writing a mock webservice, and besides legit responses I also want to generate various error conditions to see how my code responds to them. One of those would be an aborted connection. That is, I want to return NOTHING. Not even HTTP headers, not even the status line. Just brutally close the underlying TCP socket as soon as the request is received. This simulates some catastrophic error in the webservice.

Is this possible at all? Is it possible if my webserver is Apache? What about the built in webserver?

Comment: I doubt it for both the built-in server and Apache.  Even if you kill the script, the web servers are going to return a response.  You'd have to kill the web server in the middle of the connection or write your own web server (which you can do using something like ReactPHP)

Comment: sockets? socket_shutdown?

Comment: @smith - That's for sockets that you open on your own. I need it for the socket that the webserver has provided.

Comment: well im not clear at what end your working from in this question.

Comment: @Devon - I suspect as much, but I'd like to hear from someone who Knows. :)

Comment: @smith - Ahh, well, I'm writing a mock webservice for testing. My actual code (which is being tested) will connect to this webservice (via standard HTTP) and call various methods. I want the mock webservice to suddenly abort and close the connection without sending a response back to the code which is being tested.

Comment: You can send a header with forbidden value as a response header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden')

Comment: If it works via HTTP, you should not return "NOTHING". You should return [503 Service Unavailable](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.6.6.4) status code in this case.

Comment: @bdalina - Sure, and that's another test. But not the one I'm asking about here.

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase - I'm trying to simulate a network/server failure. HTTP error codes will be covered in other tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [Toxiproxy](https://github.com/shopify/toxiproxy).

> Toxiproxy is a framework for simulating network conditions. It's made specifically to work in testing, CI and development environments, supporting deterministic tampering with connections, but with support for randomized chaos and customization. Toxiproxy is the tool you need to prove with tests that your application doesn't have single points of failure.

You can use the **down** call as explained in the docs https://github.com/shopify/toxiproxy#down

Comment: Nice one! Not exactly what I wanted, but I'll keep it in mind!